# Laravel eager loading deep relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've hit a bit of a snag with Laravel and eager loading relationships. I have three models `AssetFolder`, `Asset` & `DownloadLog`

- `AssetFolder` HasMany `Asset` via `assets`
- `Asset` HasMany `DownloadLog` via `downloads`

I'm currently querying for a particular asset folder, and in doing so I'm eager loading the assets.

```php
$folder = AssetFolder::where('name', 'Example')
    ->with([
        'assets' => function (HasMany $query) {
            $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
        }
    ])->first();
```

This part works great. But for the purposes of this query, I'd also like to eager load each `Asset` associated `DownloadLog` records. I've tried solution #1 -

```php
$folder = AssetFolder::where('name', 'Corporate Assets')
    ->with([
        'assets' => function (HasMany $query) {
            $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
        },
        'assets.downloads'
    ])->first();
```

I'd now expect my `Asset` model to contain a relationship called `downloads` full of `DownloadLog` objects but unforunately that wasn't the case. The `downloads` relationship wasn't even referenced. So then I tried solution #2 -

```php
$folder = AssetFolder::where('name', 'Corporate Assets')
    ->with([
        'assets' => function (HasMany $query) {
            $query
                ->with('downloads')
                ->orderBy('name', 'asc');
        }
    ])->first();
```

This didn't work either - same result as above. Now I would have expected that to work but it didn't. So to test, I went into my `AssetFolder` model and updated my HasMany relationship method to the following -

```php
public function assets()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany(Asset::class)
        ->with('downloads');
}
```

And that works! That's great, but the problem is that 90% of the time, I don't want to pull the download logs along with the assets I'm loading. That's why I thought solution #2 would work because I thought it simply altered the HasMany query.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Chris.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - the eager loading never occurs and the relationships key remains empty on the Asset model.*

Comment: This is standard eager loading and should definitely work. Did you look at the executed queries? Does `->with('assets.downloads')` work? How is the `downloads` relationship defined?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a different relation in the AssetFolder model specifically for that purpose and eagerload with that.

```
public function assetsWithDownloads()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany(Asset::class)
        ->with('downloads');
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking to do this, it just hurts a little bit to do it - hah! Feels too much like duplication and I'm sure there is another way.

Comment: Honestly, I'm confused as to why some of your other solutions don't work. You should be able to be able to nest just fine.

Comment: Me too, it's beating me right now to be honest :( Another reason for not using the above solution, I want to then be able to limit the downloads by created_at timestamp using query params. It's very difficult to implement that if its tucked away within the model itself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could still use constraints with that. You'd have to test it out because I'm not 100%. Here's some pseudocode:

`AssetFolder::where('name', 'Corporate Assets')
->with([
    'assetsWithDownloads' => function ($query) {
        $query->where(1 = 1);
    }
])->first();`

Comment: Thank you but the problem is I want to query the download logs not the asset itself so my where query would be `$query->whereBetween('download_logs.created_at', [time1, time2]);`. Download_logs isn't even valid at this point.

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but I'm almost sure if you use constraints on nested eager loads you would be $query would be on the downloads model.

Comment: `AssetFolder::where('name', 'Corporate Assets')
->with([
    'assets.downloads' => function ($query) {
        $query->where(1 = 1);
    }
])->first();` as an example

Comment: Also something I'm noticing, you're defining the relationship:

`'assets' => function (HasMany $query) {`

You don't need put `hasMany` there. It would probably cause some form of error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185254/discussion-between-chris-and-user3325126).